# Wordpress API post search more than one word

Tags: javascript, angular, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Well I got this

```
getSearch(idQuery:string){

return this._http.get(`${this.url}posts?search=erik`).pipe(map(
  posts=>{
    
  return posts['posts']
    
  }
));
```

I'm using Wordpress API REST but I don't figure out how I can search more than one word in a string because if I use one it actually works, but if add more than one work it won't, despite I'm trying to use

> post?search=erik+alan
>
> or post?search=erik%20alan

can you give me a hand with this?

> NOTE: idQuery:String is for replace when it works.

i'll find a solution, not the best i guess

```
Search(termino:string){

let searchArray: string[] = termino.split(" ");

let forPush = [];

if (termino.length == 0)  {
  this.jobs = [];
  this.getPosts(this.jobs)  
  return
}


for (const i in searchArray) {
  const el =  searchArray[i];
  
  this._searchService.getSearch(el).subscribe( search => {

    if(search['found'] > 0){
  
      let posts = search['posts']
  
      for (const i in posts) {
        let post = posts[i];
        forPush.push(post)
      }
      
  
    } else {
      console.log('Sin resultado');
      
    }
  
  })
        
}
```

I'm using a service in angular to get the http Request, then ill make a subscription to the observable and for each word it sends Get Request...

I know, not the finest way so if you have another solution please ill be glad.

Answer (score 0):

As a replacement or in addition to the WP Rest API consider using the Xo API provided with the Xo for Angular plugin for WordPress.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/xo-for-angular/

Full disclosure, I am the plugin author.

The Xo API provides a filtering endpoint for posts that supports multiple search terms. Internally this request splits the search string on spaces and performs multiple get_posts() calls, merging the resulting IDs.

For instance there are two pages on the https://angularxo.io site titled "API" and "Guides". These can be searched for using a single call to:

https://angularxo.io/xo-api/posts/filter?postType=page&search=api+guides

Notice that the post type is provided, but not required, which helps to limit the results to a specific type of post, in this case pages. For security only post types which are marked as public can be search and retrieved in this way.

Additionally this endpoint supports pagination and other parameters similar to get_posts().

Documentation (work in progress) can be found at: https://angularxo.io

Otherwise the source for this method can help point you in the right direction: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-core/blob/master/Includes/Api/Controllers/PostsController.class.php

Xo for Angular provides a complete solution for loading Angular as a theme within WordPress though you could easily leave this feature disabled and take advantage of only the enhanced API functions.

More API docs: https://angularxo.io/api/controllers

Let me know if you think this could work for you, thanks!

Comment: thanks, I'm gonna read the docs and test it. In a few days I'm gonna try it and give you feedback about how it goes.